# How can I print the name of a variable from a list?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I've been trying to sort some variables and then print the names of the variables in sorted order, but I can't get further than this.

```
x = 0
y = 9
z = 3

numbers = [x,y,z]
numbers.sort(reverse=True)

for x in range(len(numbers)):
    print(numbers[x])
```

I want it to print

```
y
z
x
```

But I don't know how to do this and I cant seem to find anything online

Comment: If you need the names, then you need to store them as strings.

Comment: If you need theses variable names in the output, you should be using a dictionary or some other data structure to store the values. Consider that list doesn't have to contain named variables (i.e. `numbers = [1, 2, 3]`)

Comment: @Mark from the question it appears they care about ordering. This makes it a little more complicated if they're not using Python3.7+.

Comment: The list knows nothing about the original variables; only the *values* were stored in the list.

Comment: One way to access your variables and their values is to call `vars()`, which will return a dictionary of your variables (among other things). You may want to consider sorting and returning a dict to begin with anyway

`>>> variables = {var:value for var, value in vars().items() if var in ('x','y','z')}`
which returns for `variables`
`{'x': 0, 'y': 9, 'z': 3}`

Comment: @BTables If the OP is just starting, there's little reason for them to be using anything older than 3.7.

Comment: @chepner I agree they *should* be using something newer. Should is a dangerous word and assumption, though.

Comment: If you want to keep track of a list of values, have them stay in a consistent order, and have a programmatically accessible name for each value, then it sounds like you need an `OrderedDict`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: @BTables I'm assuming nothing. I'm saying that if the OP isn't using anything newer, they should stop now and *get* something newer.

Comment: @chepner agreed there, too. I was just adding context for why I left my original comment.

Answer (score 3):

First, if you care about names associated with each value, you should be using a `dict`, not individual variables. Variable names are not data.

```
numbers = {'x': 0, 'y': 9, 'z': 3}
```

You can get the output you want by sorting the *keys* of the `dict`, but making comparisons based on the value associated with each key using the `key` argument to `sorted`.

```
for k in sorted(numbers, key=numbers.get, reversed=True):
    print(k)
```

When deciding if a value `v1` is less than `v2`, `sorted` will compare them using `numbers.get`: `v1 < v2` if `numbers.get(v1) < numbers.get(v2)`.

Comment: `sorted` argument is not needed in the `sorted()` function. pretty sure it would error out. Other than that this answer is correct.

Comment: That's weird. I meant to type `reversed`. My fingers had other ideas, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments a list knows nothing about your variable names. If you care about the names you can use a dictionary which has a key-value structure. For instance you can use:

```
d = {'x' : 0, 'y':9, 'z' : 4}

d_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: 
item[1],reverse=True)}
```

To produce the following result:

```
{'y': 9, 'z': 4, 'x': 0}
```

Have also a look at [where i got this code from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value).

Answer (score 1):

```
dic ={'x':0,'y':9,'z':3}

for x in sorted( dic.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda item: item[1]):
    print(x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to store the variable names and their values:

```py
var_info = {"x": 0, "y": 9, "z": 3}
```

Then use a loop over the sorted items:

```py
import operator

for item in sorted(var_info.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print(item[1])
```